# I have problem while using tnm4j library in my NIFI program

Tags: java, apache-nifi, snmp

I am using this library in my Apache NiFi project, to perform a walk operation but it shows the following error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void net.percederberg.mibble.asn1.Asn1Parser.reset(java.io.Reader, net.percederberg.grammatica.parser.Analyzer)' at net.percederberg.mibble.MibLoader$MibSource.parseMib(MibLoader.java:970) at net.percederberg.mibble.MibLoader.loadQueue(MibLoader.java:724) at net.percederberg.mibble.MibLoader.load(MibLoader.java:550) at net.percederberg.mibble.MibLoader.load(MibLoader.java:451) at org.soulwing.snmp.provider.mibble.CachingMibRepository.load(CachingMibRepository.java:79) at org.soulwing.snmp.provider.mibble.MibbleMib.load(MibbleMib.java:226)
```

This is only a case with Apache NiFI but when i try with normal java project it will work fine.
I did not seen any dependency conflict on here can anyone help me to resolves it.
Here is My Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.pnm</groupId>
    <artifactId>pnm</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>nifi-PNMtest-processors</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.soulwing.snmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>tnm4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-mock</artifactId>
        <version>1.20.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

can you help me to resolves it.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: We would need a lot more details than that, such as a link to your code of your Maven module structure with the various POMs, as well as the version of Maven and Java you are using.

Comment: i have added my Pom.xml please let me know if anything else is needed

Comment: It looks like your `tnm4j` library is a different package than the class that's missing the method